# SAPUI5 raw applications create error 404

Tags: sapui5

I am using Web IDE of SAP.

I made simply a SAP UI5 Application projects from its template.

I didn't made any change. So it is pure a raw application.

When I run it I saw the following error inside of the Chrome console.

```
https://webidetesting6402755-a02801483.dispatcher.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)send @ sap-ui-core.js:126
```

Obviously, it doesn't get effects on the application and it can run.

I want to know how can I get rid of this error.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the Network tab in the Chrome debugging tools. There you can find which files could not be loaded.

I have tried it with a fresh app from template and found the following entries:
[image]

The app tries to load local dependent texts for the german language in my case:
It tries i18n_*de_DE*.properties first for german spoken in Germany, falls back to i18n_*de*.properties for common german, falls back to i18n_*en*.properties for english and finaly falls back to i18n.properties which are found.
Its the same pattern for messagebundles.

So these errormessages will go away if you provide all necessary localizations. But beware that there are other mechanisms that will result in error messages without affecting the functionality of the app. For example there is a component-preload.json that enables the UI5 framework to load the content of most of the files of a component like views and controllers with one request. The preload.jsons have to be build explicitly and if they do not not exist the framework loads all files of  the component individually.